# Locate parent of missing dependency in rpm package

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I've built an RPM package to hold my application, but attempting to install it produces an error about a missing faad library:

```
rpm --install dvstor-8.0-0.i386.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    libfaad.so.0 is needed by dvstor-8.0-0.i386
```

(and libfaad.so.2 is actually installed).

So one of my binaries has linked to the wrong version...  How to find out which one?

The rpm package itself has 600 files in it and `rpm -qpR dvstor-8.0-0.i386.rpm` lists 60 various dependencies, including my own few shared libs and numerous system libraries.

Other than running `ldd <file> | grep libfaad` on all those files, is there an easier way to find which file must be relinked?

I've checked the application binaries and its direct shared libraries but no joy.  Must be referenced in another file...

**EDIT 1**
For reference here is the output of rpmbuild. Note the libfaad.so.0 in the middle.  Any hints in there?

```
Processing files: dvstor-core-8.0-2.i386
Provides: libdvscfg.so.8 libdvsfileactions.so.8 libdvstc.so.8
          libdvsutils.so.8 libvlcplugin.so
Requires(interp): /bin/sh /bin/sh /bin/sh
Requires(rpmlib): rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1 
    rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 
    rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
Requires(pre): /bin/sh
Requires(post): /bin/sh
Requires(postun): /bin/sh
Requires: /bin/bash /bin/sh /usr/bin/perl libACE.so.5.5.0 libICE.so.6 libSM.so.6
   libX11.so.6 libXt.so.6 libagent++.so libavcodec.so libavcodec.so.57
   libavcodec.so.57(LIBAVCODEC_57) libavformat.so libavformat.so.57 libavutil.so 
   libavutil.so.55 libavutil.so.55(LIBAVUTIL_55) libc.so.6 libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0)
   libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.2) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2)
   libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.3) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4) libcrypto.so.10
   libdl.so.2 libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.0) libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.1) 
   libdvscfg.so.8 libdvsfileactions.so.8 libdvstc.so.8 libdvsutils.so.8 libfaac.so.0 
   libfaad.so.0 libfreeimage.so.3 libgcc_s.so.1 libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.0) libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.4)
   libgcc_s.so.1(GLIBC_2.0) libgsm.so.1 libm.so.6 libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.1)
   libmcstdh264dec.so.7 libmp3lame.so.0 libncurses.so.5 libnspr4.so libogg.so.0
   libpcap.so.1 libplc4.so libplds4.so libpthread.so.0 libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.0)
   libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.1) libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2) libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2)
   libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.4) librt.so.1 libsnmp++.so libsnmp.so.20 libstdc++.so.6
   libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3) libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4) libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.4)
   libswresample.so.2 libswscale.so.4 libswscale.so.4(LIBSWSCALE_4) libtheora.so.0 
   libtinfo.so.5 libvorbis.so.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're building the RPMs yourself, you can override the prereq scanning scripts with one of your own that then prints out when it sees the magic one you're looking for.

On my machine, I'd start digging into `/lib/rpm/redhat/find-requires`.

Comment: That's a really good clue.  Thanks.  However, I've dug into it.  In this Centos 6 machine, both /usr/lib/rpm and /usr/lib/rpm/redhat have similar contents.  I don't think either find-requires gets executed.  I've moved almost everything out of /usr/lib/rpm and rpmbuild *still* declares that libfaad is needed.  Could that be hard coded into rpmbuild?